# How can I store a varying sized array in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, xml, python-2.7

I am parsing data from a site and one of the XML categories can have multiple entries (or none at all).

I want a column called "Expansions" and then to have any number of entries listed in there. How can I store something like this in an SQL (I'm using MySQL) database?

Right now the best I can come up with is to write each entry as a long string (something like "2505, 23595, 58982, 688686")

Comment: Create a table called "cat_expansion" where you'd have a foreign key column referring to the primary key of the "category" table, and a value column for your expansion entry. For each of your expansion entries,  add a row to this table.

Comment: @user2340218 Add your comment as an answer, because it is one ;)